# xcode 7 - "openssl/pkcs7.h" file not found in xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode7

I am working on a Mac Application which uses following header files

```
#include <openssl/pkcs7.h>
#include <openssl/objects.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

I recently updated the OSX Yosemite to OSX El Capitan
and Xcode 6.4 to 7.0

The project was running successfully before update.
Now these files are not available.

What I need to do to get it working again?

One of the solution was for iOS using cocoa pods.

Is there any other way without using cocoa pods?

Answer (score 3):

Apple deprecated openssl some time ago, it's no longer part of the SDK and the library itself doesn't ship with OS X as of 10.11.

[Reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/SecureNetworkCommunicationAPIs/SecureNetworkCommunicationAPIs.html)

You didn't mention what are you using openssl for. The solution depends on your needs. If you must use openssl (e.g too much of your code depends on it) then you need to obtain openssl yourself, compile with the downloaded headers and include the library with your app distribution. Cocoapods seems like a reasonable way to manage this if you don't want to do it manually.

Or modify your code to use other libraries that do come with OS X like [Security Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801) or [CommonCrypto](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CommonCrypto).

**UPDATE:** 
Seems that Apple's documentation is a bit misleading (surprise!). The dynamic libraries for the older version of openssl (0.9.8) are still distributed with 10.11. Just checked a fresh install of 10.11 and libcrypto and libssl are still there.

If that is sufficient (for example, you just use openssl for App Store receipt validation) you can get away with obtaining just the header files from 10.10 SDK (download it from Apple with xcode 6.4) and compile your app with just the headers. You don't need the actual openssl binaries.

Comment: I am facing issue to generate signed url for fetch private content from S3 bucket using Cloud Front .But Openssl getting error in Swift. Any other solution to generate signed url. Please suggest it.

Comment: That's not related to the original question but you don't need openssl to sign AWS requests, you just need HMAC, search for Swift and HMAC on Google and you will find examples.

Comment: I tried to use HMAC  and request to cloud front  so get access denied message in response. openssl is working fine in Objective C  but not swift. Have you any demo code or resource for access private content from cloud front in swift . So please share it.

Comment: @vipulk617 this has really nothing to do with this question. If you are unable to find an HMAC Swift example by google search, I suggest that you start a new SO question for this topic.